# Always Getting Access Denied Error When I Write A File Inside Created Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, create-directory, directory-security

I'm using windows (testing in 7 and 10)

And program creating folder first. After that, i want to write a file inside created folder. But always getting access denied error. I tried every directory in  operating system. C: , programfiles, documents and project folder. Always i get that error message. Every Code is below, thank you.

app.manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Create Folder Button Method

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "FullControl";    // Or C:\\FullControl  > Doesn't matter same error
    bool exist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
    if (!exist)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    var fInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
    var Security = fInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
    Security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));

}
```

Remove Folder ReadOnly

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "FullControl";
        var fInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileAttributes f = fInfo.Attributes;
        DecipherAttributes(path, f);  //I dont now is it necessary ?
    }
```

Create and Write File Button Method

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "FullControl";
        string filePath = path + "FullControl\\Example.html";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write), Encoding.UTF8);
                tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
                tw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite), Encoding.UTF8);
            tw.WriteLine("The next line!");
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Folder Attribute Method

```
    public static void DecipherAttributes(String path ,FileAttributes f)
    {
        // To set use File.SetAttributes

        File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

        if ((f & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            Console.WriteLine("ReadOnly");

        // To remove readonly use "-="
        f -= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

        if ((f & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            Console.WriteLine("ReadOnly");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not ReadOnly");
    }
```

Comment: Just use correct variable for filePath when opening a file.

Comment: I try it before and i getted same error. But thank you. @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Users and applications are not supposed to write in `C:` or `Program Files` to prevent malicious or badly written code from overwriting important system or application files. They should only write documents to the user's Documents folder or their own data in the ProgramData folder. What are you trying to save?

Comment: @HenkHolterman the path is a relative path as shown in the first snippet. A wrong path wouldn't result in an `Access Denied` error

Comment: @HenkHolterman too many bugs in the code, *and* an attempt to write using a directory path

Comment: @EmreErol applications are not allowed to write into `Program Files` since Windows 95. Fix the bugs found by Henk then ensure you store files to the *proper* directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the code like this,  and it's worked. I think the Path.Combine() is the solution. Thanks all comments.

```
String FolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
FolderPath = Path.Combine(FolderPath,"TestFolder");
String file = Path.Combine(FolderPath,"test.html");

if (!File.Exists(file))
  {
    try
      {
          StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write), Encoding.UTF8);
          tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
          tw.Close();
          MessageBox.Show("File Created");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
   }
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman ah yeah. it's a test code but i change right now. I am using CommonApplicationData folder. Thank you.